# Electronic earth

Tags: power-electronics, earth, power-grid

I just want to know basic information about it and why it is not to be connected with main ring of electrical plant.
If there are any references for it i will be grateful.
[image]

Comment: It's not an "electronic earth", rather earth grounding. Without any detail, it can't be answered. It's about local rules, distribution contract,..

Comment: I would suggest reading parts of the NEC (National Electrical Code). Try this link there is a lot of info. Mike is the pseudo code expert in the USA.

Comment: Also known as a ‘technical earth’. Normally used in instrumentation systems to avoid coupling possible high current fault conditions from heavier electrical machinery.